# How can I add a subversion history to GIT if the GIT is younger?

Tags: svn, git, version-control

I am working on a project, and it occurs to me that I have made some changes before switching to git that I need to get to. I would like to use GIT features to work on the problem.

My question is, how can I take my .svn history and merge it with .git in such as way as to place the .svn commits in their correct historical contexts within the host git repo?

Make sense?

Comment: I have a plan to implement your suggestion, but I have been too busy to risk it all falling on my head at the moment. Don't worry, if it works, you'll get your tick!! :D

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but the [git-svn man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) uses the following commands for "tracking and contributing to the trunk of a Subversion-managed project."

```
# Clone a repo (like git clone):
        git svn clone http://svn.example.com/project/trunk
# Enter the newly cloned directory:
        cd trunk
# You should be on master branch, double-check with 'git branch'
        git branch
# Do some work and commit locally to git:
        git commit ...
# Something is committed to SVN, rebase your local changes against the
# latest changes in SVN:
        git svn rebase
# Now commit your changes (that were committed previously using git) to SVN,
# as well as automatically updating your working HEAD:
        git svn dcommit
# Append svn:ignore settings to the default git exclude file:
        git svn show-ignore >> .git/info/exclude
```

This should work as long as you have not run `git merge` or `git pull` on the branch that you plan to dcommit from, as described below. To be safe, though, you really should read through all of the caveats in the [git-svn man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) for yourself.

> For the sake of simplicity and
>   interoperating with Subversion, it is
>   recommended that all git svn users
>   clone, fetch and dcommit directly from
>   the SVN server, and avoid all git
>   clone/pull/merge/push operations
>   between git repositories and branches.
>   The recommended method of exchanging
>   code between git branches and users is
>   git format-patch and git am, or just
>   'dcommit’ing to the SVN repository.
>
> Running git merge or git pull is NOT
>   recommended on a branch you plan to
>   dcommit from because Subversion users
>   cannot see any merges you’ve made.
>   Furthermore, if you merge or pull from
>   a git branch that is a mirror of an
>   SVN branch, dcommit may commit to the
>   wrong branch.